# How to config nodejs for production enviroment on ngnix

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets

I have to develop a chat system using angularjs and nodejs.
To send and receive message i use socket.io.
For node js i create nodejs server using localhost cmd.

this is working fine but now i have to put this to live.

So i do not understand how to put nodejs code on live

i have vps server where node js is working

This is my angularjs system url

> https://app.twodegrees.io/#/

this is nodejs server link where socket is working

> https://app.twodegrees.io:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js

So my question is :
How i use nodejs code for production enviroment on ngnix server
thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to configure nginx as a reverse proxy. This will redirect requests arriving at your server to the nodeJs application running on that server.

Here is an example block that you could add to your `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file, this block will redirect requests from `app.twodegrees.io` to port 3000 on the local machine.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name app.twodegrees.io;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

for more detailed instructions, you could follow the post here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: i have follow these tutorals but  i can not understand how this work .My both code angularjs and node js is on same server. I can not understand how i send message and how nodejs get this message

Comment: But when i do this load just nodejs response not my whole site

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide your directory structure? I think it depends on if you want do serve your frontend via nginx or nodejs ...

As I understand the example configuration above only works in your case if nodejs is serving the frontend.

1. create a new directory in your node.js backend application called `public` and put in your whole frontend application
2. add `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` before you call `listen` in your `server.js`

UPDATE:

Configuration for angular frontend

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app.twodegrees.io;
    root /usr/share/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Configuration for Socket.io backend

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name socket.twodegrees.io;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: But i have to render all my html and angularjs code for front end  and i just want to listen socket message .Actullay this is chat system, this app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); load a html page i do not need this . i load html apge through angularjs and in this page i create socket and send message to app.js node js file

Comment: In this case I would recommend you start socket.io on a subdomain like socket.twodegrees.io. So finally you need 2 Nginx Configurations.